# Convert LDAP Timestamp to MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss in XSLT 1.0

Tags: datetime, xslt, ldap, xslt-1.0, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a LDAP timestamp in XSLT 1.0 to a readable format (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss) but no matter what timestamp I input the date and time is always wrong. Anyone know where my issue is or if there is a better method? Thank you!

Here is my template.

```
<!-- Get last logon date from Active Directory -->
    <xsl:call-template name="ticks-to-datetime">
        <xsl:with-param name="commonName" select="'Last-Logon-to-Domain'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="132278345110000000" />                 
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="ticks-to-datetime">
    <xsl:param name="commonName"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>

    <xsl:variable name="JDN" select="floor($value div 864000000000) + 1721426" />
    <xsl:variable name="rem-ticks" select="$value mod 864000000000"/>

    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>

    <xsl:variable name="d" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $m) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="H" select="floor($rem-ticks div 36000000000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="floor($rem-ticks mod 36000000000 div 600000000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="S" select="$rem-ticks mod 600000000 div 10000000"/>

    <xsl:element name="field">          
        <xsl:attribute name="commonName">
            <xsl:value-of select="$commonName" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '00/')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '00/')"/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($y, '0000')"/> 

        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($H, ' 00')" />    
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($M, ':00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($S, ':00')"/>   
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you included both your inputs and your outputs

Comment: You may consider 3/5/2020 to be readable, but a good proportion of your users will either misread it or consider it ambiguous. Are you really sure you want to do this?

Comment: @jwm Thanks for the reply! The input would be the 18-digit lastlogon timestamp from LDAP and the output would be the format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.

Comment: @MichaelKay Unfortunately I have no control on the backend so I cant change the accepted date format! They only support MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input represents the number of 100-nanosecond units elapsed since 1601-01-01T00:00:00, you need to change:

```
<xsl:variable name="JDN" select="floor($value div 864000000000) + 1721426" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="JDN" select="floor($value div 864000000000) + 2305814" />
```

Then your template will return the result of `03/04/2020 22:28:31` for the input of `132278345110000000`.

Comment: Oh thank this fixed it! The date/time is now correct! Thanks so much!

Also I was wondering, I am also trying to check if the value of `<xsl:with-param name="value" select="lastlogon" />` is not null before converting it.

I tried doing this in my Template but it doesnt seem to work. Any idea why?

`<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="$value !=null">
  <xsl:variable name="value" select="$value" />
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:variable name="value" select="94354848010000000" />
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>`

Comment: Please ask this question separately: the answer is too long for a comment (and so is the question). Hint 1: there is no `null` in XSLT. Hint 2: a variable defined within `xsl:choose` has no scope outside it.

Comment: It answered my question, thank you very much! Just one thing is that sometimes the date that is returned has 60 seconds so it gives an error but I will fix it with a xsl:choose and change the seconds to 59 if it is 60. Thank you!

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. It could be a rounding error. Can you post an example of such input?

Comment: Sure! Here is an example. When this timestamp is in the input 132278182796606924 the result time is this 03/04/2020 17:57:60.

Comment: Change `$S` to `<xsl:variable name="S" select="floor($rem-ticks mod 600000000 div 10000000)"/>`. Alternatively, round the input to whole seconds before extracting the individual elements.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much for your time and help!